# Is it possible to create a native UI component in Android/iOS and import into a Flutter widget?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

We're looking at a mostly Flutter based app but would like to integrate some "native" Android (Java/Kotlin) and iOS (Objective C/Swift) views and UI components. Is it possible for these to co-exist (assuming the native UI components are only displayed on their native device counterparts)?

Comment: take a look at this post: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6

Comment: As opposed to something like React-Native, this is very unrecommended in Flutter. You _can_, but don't.